# Displaying multiple feature modules that use router in the same view in Angular

Tags: angular2-routing, angular

I have an use case in which I need to have multiple modules loaded in the view at the same time. Thing is, each of those modules might be as simple as a component, or a complex Angular module with a router and everything. I guess you could call it a plugable framework.

The number of modules I have to show or who they are is dynamic (I'm getting them from a server).
[image]

My first idea is that it would be good for this case if the feature module's router wouldn't be a singleton with the main one and also if they wouldn't update the url completly.

Each of the feature module should be able to be launched as a stand-alone app if bootstrapped (therefore, I do need it to be able incorporate all Angular 4 features including the router).

I managed to get something working by playing with the router and with named router outlets (secondary routes) but not sure how good that is in the long run.

How should I approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I am in the early stages of attacking a somewhat similar scenario. In my app, the UI is organized in panels that are designed to stand alone on smaller displays, or side by side on larger. I find this approach works well for my routes, as my app is designed to edit a complex, highly hiegraphical document with many inter-related sections. e.g. User follows link on list to open detail, new detail panel appears to right... follows link on detail to related node... etc.

The solution I'm noodling with now is attempting to use an ngrx store that interacts with the router (and router-store) to dynamically create panels based upon router data. Well, technically it does not create the panels, it only serves the data that tells a component what to create and render.

I know my situ is not exactly the same as yours, but perhaps there's something in my approach that may help you find usefull or at least thought provoking.

Comment: It suits more of my app than you can imagine. I did also think of somehow using a combination between ngrx and the router for the "container" (panel) in which the apps appear. Let me know how it goes!

Comment: Update: after more playing around, I've switch gears a little bit. The store no longer plays as integral of a role in the panel routing. Instead, I am using the router config "data" element to assign multiple components to a single route. Based upon the data that comes with the activated route, the panel container component dynamically loads the panels using the route data as a guide. Basically this amounts to each route being defined as the right most panel component for that route, and the component that would be associated with the route one node up.

Comment: How is it going? Did you change the approach or did you use this one?